# Customer disconnected when paying

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, paypal-adaptive-payments

My first customer when directed to Paypal to pay got disconnected after submitting payment. Payment was not processed. Any solutions of what may have happened? I did all testing on the sandbox and it worked well. After changing to the live API I was directed to the correct page on Paypal to pay but I never tested out myself because I would be charged. Now my first customer had problems. I am using Woocommerce and setup to use Paypal adaptive payments. My e-commerce is setup for subscriptions with a one time payment and 30 days trial. Customers select the subscription they desire and proceed to cart, then checkout with Paypal. Woocommerce marked the order as completed but I did not receive any payments. Customer said that Paypal got disconnected so they did not try again afraid that they would be charged again.

Comment: what exactly have you tried? Please put that into your answer. Be extremely detailed

Comment: Added more information

Comment: For future reference, always test the live server checkout once. You can always test with a $.01 amount of something else negligible if you don't have the authority to refund it.